# for loop is not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, for-loop

```
<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>To Account</th>
            <th>From Account</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>

        <% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("data")%>

        <% for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){%>
        <tr>
            <td> <%= list.get(i)%></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

I am getting an error on the for loop line in my netbeans IDE.  It is suggesting that I need a ";" somewhere but I do have it correct don't I?

After posting this I figured out that I was missing the semi-colon in the directive jsp tag.  But now I am getting an error that the page is missing the request object?  How can this be?  I thought it was an implicit object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements within `{` block `}` must end with `;` , just the same way it is in Java, because they are indeed Java statements. `JSP` is getting translated and compiled into Java code (Servlet) by container (Tomcat)

Correct form is `<% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("data"); %>`

Just for information, in `JSP`,  declarations can take three different forms:

```
<% int a = 1; %>       // variable created for each HTTP request
<%! int b = 2; %>      // variable created for each servlet instance
<%! static c = 3; %>   // static variable shared by all instances of servlet
```

In any form, it has to be closed with `;`

Note that on the other hand an expression `<%= %>` is not a Java statement, so accordingly, expression block `<%= ... %>` *does not* require no semicolon at the end.

Also make sure that you have added import for ArrayList on the top of the `JSP` page, as by default `JSP` page has access only to `java.lang.* package`

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
```

Comment: Hummm.....
I have a piece of code which works perfectly without ; at the end of a for loop.... But in another piece of code I'm working now, it doesn't works with/ without.

So...it seems it doesn't the corret answer :/

A.k.a: 

<% for (Tarea tarea : tareas) { %> BunchOfCode <% } %>

What's mandatory is a proper spacing (with tabs min.) between the lastJavaChar and closing  %>

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error on the `for` loop line because you didn't close the previous statement with a semicolon. This one:

```
<% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("data")%>
```

Which should have a semicolon at the end, like this:

```
<% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("data");%>
```